# sabbath forgiveness?

Tags: shabbat

My job requires me to work weekends, incuding saturday. I am vexed in my spirit to work on saturday the sacred day of our forefathers. I get off at 3:30pm. What should I do about this? Is it lawfull for me to continue the Sabbath after I get off work at 3:30? this just makes me grieved in the pit of my stomache.

So is it lawfull to take up sabbath after I get off work at 3:30 pm and pray for Hashem's forgiveness?

Comment: Every minute counts.

Comment: eliyah, I'm very sorry to hear that you are in this quandary. You now have a link to another question with a bunch of valuable answers, which I hope you find useful in understanding the associated issues. I strongly recommend that, in addition, you speak to your rabbi about your situation for both practical and spiritual guidance.

Comment: the answer lies within the question: "the sacred day of our forefathers". You will only find peace with the question and the consequent solution after that changes to "My sacred day"!!!